# Flatten array inside another array in php

Tags: php

I have an array that is built as follows

```
foreach($details as $data)
{
    $loans[] = [
            'name' => 'Details',
            [
                'name' => 'id',
                'value' => 1
            ],
            [
                'name' => 'Date',
                'value' => '2015'
            ],
            [
                'name' => 'Purpose',
                [
                    'name' => 'Code',
                    'value' => 123
                ]
            ],
            getFees($data)
        ];
}
```

I need to use the `fees` from the `getFees` function and have those values set at the same level as the 'name' => 'Details' above.

```
private function getFees($data)
{
    foreach($data as $item){
        $values[] = [
            'name' => 'type',
            'value' => 'Interest'
        ];
    }
    return $values;
}
```

So the above produces the following:

```
Array
(
    [name] => Details
    [0] => Array
    (
        [name] => Details
        [0] => Array
            (
                [name] => id
                [value] => 1
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [name] => Date
                [value] => 2015
            )
         [2] => Array
            (
                [name] => Purpose
                [0] => Array
                 (
                      [name] => Code 
                      [value] => 123
                 )
            )
          [3] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => Type
                        [value] => Interest

                    )
            )
      )
 )
```

But I don't want that [3] array to be another level deeper, I simply want:

```
 Array
(
    [name] => Details
    [0] => Array
    (
        [name] => Details
        [0] => Array
            (
                [name] => id
                [value] => 1
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [name] => Date
                [value] => 2015
            )
         [2] => Array
            (
                [name] => Purpose
                [0] => Array
                 (
                      [name] => Code 
                      [value] => 123
                 )
         [3] => Array
           (
                 [name] => Type
                 [value] => Interest
           )          
     )
 )
```

Clearly I'm missing something - if i try to do array_merge, outside the loop, then the `fees` array is outside the `Details` array.

If the `getFees` function only sets the array to one single element, then it works fine, but I need to allow for multiple elements, hence the `$values[]` assignment.

How do i produce the array as required above ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you've currently written it, getFees() would have to return **multiple values** in order to achieve the desired array. Since a function can only return one thing, you'll need to rewrite the code.

I recommend you take the getFees() call out of your $loans array, and instead call it afterwards, merge the results with the $loans array.

```
foreach($datum as $data){
    $temp = array(
        // your data
    );

    $temp = array_merge($temp, getFees($data));

    $loans[] = $temp;
}
```

Comment: thanks but i forgot to add the code (i've edited now) to show that the initial assignment of `loans` is in a foreach loop, so i can't put it outside, otherwise the resultant array contains the fees data outside the specific array element it should be in .. hope that makes sense

Comment: The answer still stands. Since getFees() is returning an array, and you want that arrays elements to be at the end of the loans array, you simply merge the two.

Comment: Ahh... now I understand. You need a third variable (temp).